# Display multiple chatter components

Tags: visualforce, chatter

How does one display more than one chatter components? I need to build a visualforce page with two chatter components side by side; but filtered by different topics.

e.g.

```
<apex:page>
  <chatter:feed entityId="${user}" />
  <chatter:feed entityId="${customObject}" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. You will have to hack your way to accomplish this.

You will need 3 VF pages.

- VF Page 1 has a chatter feed for a User

  ```
  <chatter:feed entityId="ENTER USER ID HERE" />
  ```
- VF Page 2 has a chatter for the custom object

  ```
  <chatter:feed entityId="ENTER Custom OBJECT ID HERE" />
  ```
- VF Page 3 shows both pages inside an iframe.

> ```
> <table style="width:100%">
>     <tr>
>         <td style="width:50%">
>             <iframe src="URL TO VF PAge 1" width="100%"  height="PLAY with this number"/>
>         </td>
>         <td style="width:50%">
>             <iframe src="URL TO VF PAge 2" width="100%" height="PLAY with this number"/>
>         </td>
>     </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Hopefully that will work.

Good luck!!

Luis Luciani